# Not able to Convert string xml to Node using java and iterate

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to convert xml string data to NodeList and iterate.. But, I'm not able to. I wanted to iterate the nodelist and fetch the xml data inside it. Here is my code

```
    String arrayOfErrorContext = "<item><errorCode>1</errorCode><errorDescription></errorDescription></item>" +
            "<item><errorCode>1</errorCode><errorDescription></errorDescription></item>";
    if(arrayOfErrorContext!= null && !arrayOfErrorContext.isEmpty()) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try
        {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( arrayOfErrorContext) ) );
            NodeList nList1 = document.getElementsByTagName("item");
            //iteration Logic on nList1
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Anything wrong in the above code?

Comment: @wero, so is anything wrong then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all correct the XML string. pu a root element like ..

you are doing it in wrong way..
You need to convert string into dom.Document. and then try to get NodeList from it.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
        DocumentBuilder builder;  
        try  
        {  
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
            Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( arrayOfErrorContext ) ) );  
            NodeList nList1 = document.getElementsByTagName("item");
            //iteration Logic on nList1
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
```

in this iteration logic get a node

```
 nList1.item(0).getFirstChild()
```

and iterate by fetching next node using.

```
 .getNextSibling()
```

example iteration Logic:

```
public static void recurseNode(Node node) {
        System.out.println(node.getNodeName() + node.getTextContent());

        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                // calls this method for all the children which is Element
                recurseNode(currentNode);
            }
        }
```

complete code:

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class EnterExitListener {

    static Node e = null;

    public static void main(String[] argd) {
        String arrayOfErrorContext = "<root><item><errorCode>1</errorCode><errorDescription></errorDescription></item><item><errorCode>1</errorCode><errorDescription></errorDescription></item></root>";

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(
                    arrayOfErrorContext)));
            NodeList nList1 = document.getElementsByTagName("root");
            int i = nList1.getLength();

            e = nList1.item(0).getFirstChild();
            e.getChildNodes();
            recurseNode(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void recurseNode(Node node) {
        System.out.println(node.getNodeName() + node.getTextContent());

        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                // calls this method for all the children which is Element
                recurseNode(currentNode);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No. Sorry, it shows [Fatal Error] :1:76: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: i have edited the answer hope it helps you. also the XML string you have provided it contains some problems correct it

Comment: I'm still getting that error. Can you please copy the following question code and try again? I'll update the question along with ur changes.

Comment: enclose <item> tags in some other tag like:  <root> specify items here </root>

Comment: Yes. I can add as a static one

Comment: Can you please send the iterate logic where I can fetch errorCode/

Comment: I'm able to get only the package names. Here is my code for iterating.. println "nlist "+nList1
                for (int i = 0; i < nList1.getLength(); i++) {

                    Element element = (Element) nList1.item(i);
                    println "Element "+element

                    NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("item");
                    println "name "+name

                    Element line = (Element) name.item(0);

                }

Comment: Can you please apply the iteration logic to the above code? Because my code looks a bit long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89580/discussion-between-nizam-and-java-ledge).

Comment: Hey, I'm having some issue with my code. Can you please check it? I can send the code to your email.